# Display diagonal line when only one point is selected

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a graph like this:

[image]

This is my dimension tab:

[image]

This is my expression tab:

[image]

The third dimension is there to create the diagonal line (see the linear reference at the bottom left in my expression tab). I got the idea from [here](https://community.qlik.com/message/56958)!

When I select only one point in the graph the line disappears (see below). But I want it to remain there. Other solutions to display a diagonal line are welcome too. Thanks for the help!!

[image]

This is my csv file:

```
SA,PLAN,IST
tyre,0.3,0.2
steering wheel,0.7,0.9
seat heater,0.9,0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround is to create a second scatter chart which will only show up when only one entity is selected. Then make the background of that scatter chart transparent and add a diagonal line object. You need also to fix the axis both to 100%.

[image]